# How to access environment variables in JSON file for Golang project?

Tags: json, security, go, environment-variables, environment

My team is using Golang for coding, and we put all configurations in a `conf.json`, interesting part shown below, and another `config_schema.json` file for the json validation.

```
{
"host": "192.168.0.34",
"port": "5678",
"username": "test_user",
"password": "random_pass",
"dbName": "dummy"
}
```

My question is, can I define environment variables .e.g $USER and $PASS and use them as below or there is a proper way to achieve this for security purpose?

```
{
"host": "192.168.0.34",
"port": "5678",
"username": "$USER",
"password": "$PASS",
"dbName": "dummy"
}
```

Comment: The encoding/json package does not expand environment variables. You will need to write some code to do this.  The function https://godoc.org/os#ExpandEnv may be helpful.

Comment: Or you could do it in the shell, by writing a start script that writes the JSON with env vars expanded before starting the application.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's too late since the question it's 1 year old
But you can use a combination of https://golang.org/pkg/os/#ExpandEnv
and https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler

In order to use Unmarshaler you should have a `struct` corresponding to your json. then you can override the default method and substitute only fields you want to. The simpler example is shown below

```golang
result := os.ExpandEnv(jsonString)
```

live example: https://play.golang.org/p/78C2zyYP6vL

Answer (score 0):

We end up using the env var, and define username and password in Gitlab CI environment variables and enable masked so that the they will not display in the log.